# Parsing JSON - "Variable 'jsonObject' used before being initialized

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem with a JSON library I am using for an iOS 9.0 project, on Xcode 7 beta 5, running on OS X El Cap.

I followed [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial#comments) to make a part of my app that involved some basic MapKit functionality. In this "part", I have to parse JSON data into "issue locations" (it's an app for a school newspaper, and we're going to have a map of all locations where they drop off issues).

Here is my problem (I don't understand it, as I am a beginner iOS developer). I get an error on the following line, that says "Variable 'jsonObject' used before being initialized".

The line in question is the third "paragraph" in the "loadInitialData" function.

```
if let jsonObject = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject],
```

And here is all of my code for the "MapViewController.swift" file governing everything that happens in my MapKit view.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

// Map View outlet declaration
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

// Hamburger button declaration
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

// Creating a variable to hold the "IssueLocation" objects from the JSON file
var issueLocations = [IssueLocation]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Hamburger button configuration
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    // Setting the Map type to standard
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard

    // Configuring locationManager and mapView delegate
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    mapView.delegate = self

    // Set the center of campus as the first location, before we show the actual user location
    let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 44.226397, longitude: -76.495571)
    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

    // Centering map on center of campus
    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    loadInitialData()
    mapView.addAnnotations(issueLocations)

    // Show user location and start updating user location
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

//        // Show a sample issue location on the Map
//        let IssueLocation = IssueLocation(locationName: "Stirling Hall, West  Entrance", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.22468034747186, longitude: -76.49805217981339))
//        
//        mapView.addAnnotation(IssueLocation)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location!.coordinate
}

func loadInitialData() {

    let fileName = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("IssueLocations", ofType: "json");
    var readError : NSError?
    var data: NSData?

    do {
        data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: fileName!, options: NSDataReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    } catch _ {
        data = nil
    }

    var error: NSError?
    let jsonObject: AnyObject!
    if let data = data {

        do {
            jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        } catch _ {
            jsonObject = nil
        }

    }

    if let jsonObject = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject],
        let jsonData = JSONValue.fromObject(jsonObject)?["data"]?.array {
            for issueLocationJSON in jsonData {
                let issueLocation = IssueLocation.fromJSON(issueLocationJSON.array!)
                        issueLocations.append(issueLocation)



            }

    }
}

// Checking location authorization status and requesting permission from user if status is not ".AuthorizedWhenInUse"
func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
     } else {
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `if let data = data` evaluates to `false`, then `jsonObject` will not be initialized since all the initialization for that object happens inside that if statement. Try initializing `jsonObject` to `nil` when you create the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did the job. For other beginners, all I did was replace "let jsonObject : AnyObject!" with "var jsonObject : AnyObject! = nil"